# how can i make a gui checkbox trigger a macro in autohotkey?

Tags: macros, autohotkey, gui

I'm trying to make a GUI which will run different sets of macros depending on which boxes i check. but i dont want them to run until i click a GO button. the help files mention that checkboxes can store their checked or unchecked state in a variable and have been trying to use an if statement to get them to run, im not getting any error messages anymore it just doesnt run. this is what it looks like so far:

Gui, Add, Checkbox, vKCPM, KCPM
Gui, Add, Button, Default gButtonGo, Go
Gui, Show, w500 h300, Products
return

ButtonGo:
if KCPM = 1 
    msgbox, kcpm checked
return

GuiClose:
Gui, Destroy

Comment: Please could you edit your question to add the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing a Submit

```
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vKCPM, KCPM
Gui, Add, Button, Default gButtonGo, Go
Gui, Show, w500 h300, TestApp
Return

ButtonGo:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
If KCPM = 1
   msgbox, yes
else
    msgbox, no
Return

GuiClose:
Gui, Destroy
```